# A Countable Powerset -- Where am I wrong?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Cantor's Theorem seems pretty airtight to me. So what is wrong with the following reasoning?

Consider $X = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. We say $X$ contains uncountably many **sets**. But the only sets that exist are those asserted to exist by the axioms. So if we consider each of the axioms that assert more sets, starting with $\emptyset$, we have one set. The pairing axiom can only produce countably many more. Union gives us up to one more set per set in existence. Powerset also gives us up to one more set per set in existence. Separation and replacement gives us countably many more sets per set in existence. Infinity gives us more more set. Foundation gives us one more set per set in existence. Choice also only gives us one more set per set in existence.

It seems to me that the axioms only ever define countably many sets. So when we consider all the subsets of a set, there might be uncountably many *things* that satisfy the condition of being a subset, but only countably many of them are possibly *sets*. If sets can only contain sets, $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ must be countable.

---

I'm still not getting the argument about parameters coming from *somewhere*. I understand the notion of parameters in the context of definability *in a structure*, but this question is about a theory (ZFC), whose axioms are well formed formulas in the language of set theory ($\forall,\land,\neg,\in$). Thus technically all the separation and replacement axioms do not contain any parameters, right?

Considering the example set:

$$ X = \{ (n,k) | 2^{\aleph_n} = \aleph_k \} $$

When all the subsets of $\mathbb{N}^2$ are added, surely $X$ is among them? We can say with certainty is that $X$ exists at this stage (because it is definable...or perhaps we can only say there is a plethora of possibilities for $X$ in existance?), but we would be unable to enumerate the pairs (ie say *which* subset of $\mathbb{N}^2$ it is) without making more assertions about the continuum.

I like this idea that there can exist subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ that are undefinable without parameters that come from sets of a higher rank. Perhaps there is a forcing notion that makes $X$ one of these in a particular model. But are there uncountably many of them?

Comment: Jonny, the point of my comment about this $X$ is that it is that you suggested that only sets which are definable from *previously* defined sets exist. And while this $X$ is indeed definable, it isn't *necessarily* definable as a subset of $\Bbb N$, just from what we have accumulated by the time we generated $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Additionally, look at the formulation of separation and replacement. Separation begins with $\varphi(x,p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ and it says that for every choice of parameters $p_1,\ldots,p_n$, and every set $w$ there is a unique set $y$ such that $x\in y$ if and only if $x\in w$ and $\varphi(x,p_1,\ldots,p_n)$. These are the parameters and they can come from wherever you want them to come in the set theoretic universe.

Comment: Surely the rank of $X$ is $\omega$, and therefore it gets added at this stage? If I have a theory with the property that every model contains the elements 1 and 2, but it is not provable in the theory whether $x$ is equal to 1 or 2 (but has to be one of them), I'd say the set containing $x$ is definable and exists. It just happens to be the case that in some models, the set containing $x$ is the set containing 1, and in other models it is the set containing 2. But the set containing $x$ is definitely not a new, unique set that increases the total number of sets in my model.

Comment: Let me say that *again*. The set of $n$ such that $\aleph_n$ violates the continuum hypothesis (for that specific cardinal) can be undefinable as a subset of $\Bbb N$ along with addition, multiplication, whatever. It is added at rank $\omega+1$ but it is **UNDEFINABLE** as such subset. But it (1) might be definable using set theoretic formulas which are *not* bounded by addition and multiplication and whatnot; and (2) might be definable using parameters from the universe (trivially or less trivially). Your question makes it seem as if the only sets added are those definable from [...]

Comment: [...] the basic structure of the natural numbers, whatever it might be. But this is not true. There are sets definable using formulas and using parameters, and sometimes sets might be definable, essentially only by the formula $\varphi(x,A)=x\in A$ where $A$ is the parameter (so the definition is trivial).

Comment: Let me add something that I explained to one of my students some time ago, which is the difference between what exists and what we can prove that exists. If I want to say something about an arbitrary student of mine, I can only use what I know is provable about every person, for example that they were born to a mother and father; that they breathe oxygen; whatever. However, some of my students might be married, others not, some with children, others not. It is even plausible that I will have classroom full of single people, and another all married +2 people. [...]

Comment: [...] I can't prove that any of my students is married, and I can't disprove that either. Some of the sets of $\Bbb N$ are definable using no parameters, others are definable with some parameters, and more might be definable only with a trivial formula which makes them undefinable in any meaningful way (namely they are parameters in a formula defining that set). Your question, *again*, hints and points towards a common mistake, that no parameters are allowed, or that the sets are somehow definable from previous generated sets. This is not true. And I don't know how to make this any clearer.

Comment: I understand, but I disagree. I'm not saying parameters are not allowed, I'm saying they aren't necessary. Sure, we can add them and gain expressiveness; even though you don't know which students are married, you still have a class. If you had more parameters you might know more about your class. However, with parameters, I can still only define countably many subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. Thus the issue lies entirely in the proof that $\text{ZFC} \models |\mathcal{P}(X)| > |X|$.

Comment: Fine. You disagree. I have nothing more to add here.

Answer (score 4):

You hit some sort of circularity with separation.

While there are only countably many formulas (and that countable collection is not really countable from the standpoint of set theory. It's nonexistent, since it's a part of the meta-theory); these formulas are allowed to have parameters.

All you really show here is that a lot of the subsets of $\Bbb N$ will be definable using separation axioms of the form $\varphi(x,p):= x\in p$ where $p$ is a parameter, and $A=\{x\in\Bbb N\mid\varphi(x,A)\}$. It's a bit of circular, but not if you really think about it.

But there is another issue here. Separation axioms don't rely on "previously added sets" in the hierarchal order of things. Note that $\{(n,k)\mid 2^{\aleph_n}=\aleph_k\}$ is a definable subset of $\Bbb N^2$ (and so by encoding it defines a subset of $\Bbb N$), but it's not really added after adding $\Bbb N$. It will only be added after we've added a lot more, namely all the $\aleph_n$'s and all their power sets.

And we can add all sort of crazy definitions like that. The freedom to use parameters, and to use formulas which address the entire set theoretical universe and not just $\Bbb N$, show that there are uncountably many subsets. The power set axiom just ensures that there is just "set many" of them.

What's even more important is to understand that the axioms don't "define" the structure". Instead the structure is *given* and we check that it satisfies the axioms. Does your argument mean that any model of a countable language is countable, just because? Not really. It just shows that a countable language can define only countably many elements in a model (unless you allow parameters).

Let me point a similarity with the von Neumann construction of $V$ (or really, any other hierarchal construction). The sets come from *somewhere*. They already exist. We just show that we can write the universe as a limit of a hierarchy of sets. Similarly in your question, the sets already exist, the axioms don't bring them to life, they just allow us to show that particular sets exist.

Comment: I love the example you give of a definable subset of $ \mathbb N^2 $.  However, is it not possible that such a subset may have an alternative extension that relied only on, say, the arithmetic of $ \mathbb N $.  It seems unlikely perhaps, but how can one claim uniqueness for this definition.  Is this a well known subset whose properties are well understood so that no arithmetic relation between $ n $ and $ k $ will suffice.

Comment: Sorry, I see my stupidity now.  Obviously this relates to the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: Nick, of course I can't. In a model where $\sf GCH$ holds this set is simply $\{(n,n+1)\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$, and in a model where $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_\omega$ this is an empty set. So since I can't tell what is the explicit content of this set, I can't tell you that it has another definition as an arithmetical set. But I know that it can *not* have such definition. Begin by forcing $\sf GCH$ (below $\aleph_\omega$ is enough), add a Cohen real and use it to force the values of the  continuum of the $\aleph_n$'s, the Cohen real is not arithmetical, so in the last model it's not an arithmetical set

Comment: I am aware that the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem implies that any theory in a countable language must have a countable model (thus ZFC has a countable model). My argument is not that every model must be countable, but Cantor's theorem must mean that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is uncountable in every model. How can this hold in a countable model? However, I really thought my question was separate from the Skolem Paradox -- I'm comfortable with the idea that a statement about the existence of uncountable sets can be true in a countable model, I just don't see it with the power set.

Comment: @Jonny: I think that you missed the point of my answer.

Comment: Could you clarify your third paragraph? Are you saying the the number of parameters can be uncountable?

Comment: @Jonny: No, I'm saying that the collection from which we can choose parameters from is uncountable. Moreover, we can use the set itself as a parameter, since we don't "add it", it is already *given* to us.

Comment: How is that true if the only sets that exist belong to the model? The only 'parameters' available are constant symbols and variables. It seems to me that your uncountable collection only exists in an uncountable language.

Comment: @Jonny: Existence is a semantical property. This means that a set exists if and only if it's an element of the model. Moreover the parameters are not elements of the language, parameters are free variables that are allowed to be assigned arbitrarily from the model. And as I repeatedly point out "uncountable" is an internal term here, not an external term.

Comment: I don't see any previous explicit reference to the fact that "uncountable" is an internal term, which is apparently the critical fact in question. All the examples here seem to reference a particular model which is already assumed to be uncountable.

Comment: I'd be very happy to hear what whoever downvoted this answer has to say. Why is it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the crux of the issue is grasping that Cantor's theorem requires the bijection to exists **in the model**.

When we say $X = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is "uncountable", it simply means that there does not exist a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $X$ in whatever model. So, if we let $M$ be a countable model of ZFC, the cardinality of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is"countable" in a metalanguage sense of the term -- each of the subsets are in a one to one correspondence with the "countable" $\varphi$ that define them. However, there exists an injective function $f_i$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $X$ such that $f_i \in M$, but there does not exist a bijective function $f_b$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $X$ such that $f_b \in M$ (else $M$ would not be a model of ZFC).

I see now that my question was, in fact, equivalent to the [Skolem Paradox](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-skolem/). In my question I assert that the only sets that exist are those that provably exist from the axioms, but this assertion is not provable from ZFC. However, it is true in a model constructed by the downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem. Inside such a model, the powerset of the natural numbers is uncountable, even though it is countable in whatever meta-model the construction of this model took place.

Comment: Suppose that you have an uncountable model of $\sf ZFC$ which includes all the subsets of $\Bbb N$. For example some $V_\kappa$ with $\kappa$ inaccessible. Skolem's paradox does not apply here sine the model and the universe agree on the power set operation. How do you resolve the problem that you asked about using your answer here?

Comment: What do you mean by the model and the universe? Why doesn't Skolem's paradox apply? Inside your $V_{\kappa}$ (and every other model), by downward LST there exists a countable model $M$ that thinks ZFC. $M$ also thinks the powerset of the natural numbers is uncountable even though $V_{\kappa}$ thinks this set is countable. The argument in my question fails because the notion of being "countable" is not absolute. I think it would be interesting to try coding/enumerating the axioms of ZFC in your $V_{\kappa}$, constructing a countable $M$, and then coding/enumerating the axioms of ZFC in $M$.

Comment: You're not answering my question. Nor your original question either. You asked, if there are only countably many formulas, how can the power set of the natural numbers be uncountable. In this answer of yours you say "Oh, that's the Skolem paradox", but the Skolem paradox is when you talk about a countable model of set theory. But of course a countable model of set theory has only countably many sets, in particular countably many subsets of $\Bbb N$. But as I said, your question doesn't have "countable model" in it. So how does *this* answer resolves the case when the model is $V_\kappa$?

Comment: I said the question was equivalent to, not identical to, the Skolem paradox. Both my question and the Skolem paradox are paradoxical because the notion of countability is not absolute. Also, I think the question is implicitly constructing a countable model.

Comment: I don't see how the question is equivalent to the Skolem paradox, or has anything to do with it. But it's your question, so you probably have an internal question in mind and there was some bits of dissonance between your internal question and the way I internalized your external question.

Comment: I'm just trying to learn the subject -- you seem like an expert :) I accepted my answer because it was what set the lightbulb off for me, and I am enjoying attempting to defend it! I didn't want to accept that sets just come from anywhere, but I think I understand your answer better now that I have a few more months of study behind me.

Comment: It's an important point, the parameters, and many people fail to remember it. Not to mention that just because the axioms govern the universe doesn't mean that every element of the universe is definable. Sometimes things just exist, and we have no "reasonable" explanation why.

Comment: Your edit is not quite true either. If $M$ is a model which is a generic extension by some real number $x$ of the model $N$, it is not necessarily the case that a particular $x$ can be defined using a formula (especially since you ignore the fact that the parameters can vary all over the model, trivializing a lot of the definitions). But the statement "$M$ is a generic extension of $N$ by adding a generic real of this type" is expressible in the language of set theory, so it will be true in the countable model. So the countable model will have "not provably existing sets" as well.